# AngularJS radio buttons ng-repeat value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, radio-button

I'm creating radio buttons with ng-repeat and would like the selected button's name value to appear below.

Here is my view:

```
<span ng-repeat="weight in weights">
  <input type="radio" name="weight" value="{{weight.name}}" id="weight{{weight.name}}" ng-checked="weight.checked">
  <label for="weight{{weight.name}}">{{weight.name}}</label>
</span>
<p>Weight: {{weight.name}}</p>
```

Here is my controller:

```
$scope.weights = [
  {
    name: 1,
    checked: true
  },
  {
    name: 2,
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 3,
    checked: false
  }
];
```

[Here is my Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9kF52SHTrvWwhFJN8zf9?p=preview).

How can I get the weight to appear in the paragraph tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should maintain value of radio in one of the `ng-model` & use $parent. to define it in controller scope rather than in `ng-repeat` like here

**Markup**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-init="radioValue=1">
  <span ng-repeat="weight in weights">
    <input type="radio" name="weight" ng-model="$parent.radioValue" ng-value="{{weight.name}}" id="weight{{weight.name}}" ng-checked="weight.checked">
    <label for="weight{{weight.name}}">{{weight.name}}</label>
  </span>
  <p>Weight: {{radioValue}}</p>
</body>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9kF52SHTrvWwhFJN8zf9?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies in understanding how $scope works in angular.
The quick solution is to use $parent.selectedName, where $parent refers to the parent scope. This is because each iteration of ng-repeat creates a scope of itself. (see [enter link description here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

See this https://jsfiddle.net/pankaj01/Xsk5X/3074/
 the JS is

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

$scope.weights = [
  {
    name: 1,
    checked: true
  },
  {
    name: 2,
    checked: false
  },
  {
    name: 3,
    checked: false
  }
];
```

}