# AngularJS: Radio buttons in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I've got  a set of radio buttons in a `ng-repeat`, following what I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29750708/angularjs-radio-buttons-ng-repeat-value). I just can't figure out how to add an `ng-model` to it.

```
   <tr ng-repeat="service in selectservice.services track by $index">
          <td>
            <input type="radio" name="serviceSelections" ng-value="{{service.name}}" id="service{{service.name}}">
          </td>
          <td>
            <h3>
              {{service.name}}
            </h3>
            <p>{{service.caption}}</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

With this controller:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('pb.ds.selectservice').controller('SelectServiceController', function($log) {
    var _this = this;

    _this.selectedService = 0;

    _this.services = [
      {
        selected: false,
        name: 'Postmates',
        caption: 'Guaranteed delivery within time'
      },
      {
        selected: true,
        name: 'Deliv',
        caption: 'Guaranteed delivery within time',
      },
      {
        selected: false,
        name: 'Roadie',
        caption: 'Guaranteed delivery within time',
      }
    ];
  });
})();
```

and, in my route, for this view:

```
        content: {
          controller: 'SelectServiceController as selectservice',
          templateUrl: 'modules/select-service/templates/select-service.html'
        },
```

The radio group correctly shows the second radio selected.  But how do I update the model? What, exactly *is* the model?  I have tried `ng-model="selectservice.selectedService"` which should be `0`, but then *no* radio is selected.

Comment: Refer - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D .. You basically need to give same `ng-model` for each `radio button`

Comment: In my case it's in a repeat so all of them will have the same ng-model.  I have tried `service.name`, `service.selected`, nothing works.

Comment: Radio buttons are always a part of a group and only one of that group can be selected. That means a group of radio buttons will have only one value and therefore you need same ng-model for all radio buttons related to a group.

Comment: @Steve Can you please check if you have assigned `ng-model`. I do not see that in your `html`

Comment: I wound up using code from the deleted answer: `<input type="radio" ng-model="service.selected" name="serviceSelections" id="service{{service.name}}">`

Comment: I updated the answer with proper explanation. Please have a look @Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a model in your controller to assign the radio button group  an ng-model. In your case it should be

```
    _this.selectedService = "";
```

Since it appears that you want to get the selected service's name.

Setting your HTML like below will make it work.

```
<tr ng-repeat="service in selectservice.services track by $index">
          <td>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="selectservice.selectedService" value="{{service.name}}" id="service{{service.name}}">
          </td>
          <td>
              {{service.name}}
            <p>{{service.caption}}</p>
          </td>
      </tr>
```

After this whatever button you check, your _this.selectedService will update with the corresponding button's name. So if you select the "Deliv" radio button, your _this.selectedService will get the value "Deliv". I hope found your answer